# Mac OS X unable to see Windows PC in network

Tags: windows, macos, networking, mac

I have latest version of OS X Mountain Lion. My Mac is joined to Microsoft based network. Everything seems fine when I used Snow Leopard & Lion. But I got problem browsing another network PC since Mountain Lion. They are no longer listed in my network. I've checked WINS configuration & everything seems fine.

Could anyone here help me solving this problem?

Comment: What OS is the windows computer, is your firewall on?  Can the Mac ping the Windows computer?

Answer (score 0):

The OSX firewall needs to allow the broadcasts from the Windows network for your Mac to be able to "see" which systems are available.

Lion is more strict in its default firewall rules as the previous versions and it won't do this "out of the box".

If you tell the Mac to allow Sharing files/printers it will open the firewall for this. Even if you are not really sharing anything from the Mac, but just using the Mac as a client for other shares.

I can't recall the exact steps from the top of my head. I'm in the office now which is Windows only. But I've got 2 Lion Mac's at home that have no issue accessing Windows shares/printers.

P.S: If you have consistent issues with establishing connections with a specific Windows box you can install the "Bonjour printer services for Windows" (free download from Apple) on the Windows machine. This makes the Windows PC advertize itself to any Mac on the network using the native Apple protocol, which is quicker and more reliable than the normal Windows broadcast mechanism.

Comment: Note that Apple's Bonjour can cause network problems, e.g. ["Bonjour" service may cause issues in resolving DNS names in the .local zone](https://help.rm.com/technicalarticle.asp?cref=tec3015691).

Comment: @AndrewMorton True. But this is a very old question and a very old problem. Later versions of the Bonjour for Windows software are better behaved as far as I know.

Comment: I think it might be that Windows 10 is more tolerant of Bonjour's behaviour rather than Bonjour being better behaved. Either way, I don't allow it on our work network, at least when we get to use the office nowadays.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Why would you use .local domains in the workplace anyway? I don't ban Bonjour (in fact some of our developers need it to test if our own mDNS products are compatible with it), but we do ban .local use. If I catch anyone with a .local setup (I've got a honey-pot running to detect them)  he/she is ordered to use the proper DNS configuration. If they don't comply their equipment will be placed in another VLAN with no direct conection to the rest of the network. It's really amazing how quickly they suddenly don't need .local anymore.

Comment: The link in my earlier comment was only to a specific example of problems coming from Bonjour - I didn't want to use a "lmgtfy" type link. I see from further investigation that .local isn't recommended since 2013 - why didn't they tell me? :( Yet Bonjour still causes problems with a one PC, two switches and a router on the same LAN, and one printer setup *for us*.